# What is the use case of using "tensorflow.keras.layers.Add()([x1, x2])" instead of "x1 + x2"?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I looked but couldn't find the answer in docs, or anywhere else. Maybe I'm not correct about the functionality of Add().

Comment: Nothing in particular. In some cases `Add()` can be useful (e.g. in a `Sequential` model you can't use `+` - unless you have a custom `Lambda` layer). But as you can imagine using `+` along with `Lambda` gives more flexible/customizability than using `Add()` - which can be a plus if you're performing custom logic